# What are the embouchure differences for the brass family instruments?

Tags: brass, physiology, embouchure

I play trumpet, but have little to no experience on other brass instruments. In terms of the physiology involved, how does the embouchure change from one (family of) instrument to another? Are certain muscles or muscle groups used more or less across instruments? Does the embouchure shape change? Aperture size (presumably)? Differences in tongue position? Pressure (or lack thereof) against the mouthpiece? Etc.

---

This question is partially addressed in several other places, but I'm looking to compile a generally applicable answer with more specific physiological descriptions of the embouchure that provided elsewhere.

- [What are the pros and cons of doubling on two brass instruments?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-doubling-on-two-brass-instruments)
- [Are there conflicting requirements for technique between large and small brass instruments](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11804/are-there-conflicting-requirements-for-technique-between-large-and-small-brass-i)
- [What are the advantages of different mouthpiece sizes?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11058/what-are-the-advantages-of-different-mouthpiece-sizes)